# Outlook 2010 w/ Exchange 2003 Expired Certificate

Tags: exchange-2003, ssl-certificate

Whenever I launch Outlook 2010 against my Exchange 2003 server, I receive a message for a certificate that has expired. The certificate did, indeed expire, and I have replaced it on the OWA IIS instance (also on the same server as exchange).

However, I cannot figure out where else this certificate is installed so that I can update it as well.

Comment: SSL certificates are also stored locally on client computers. Have you tried going to `Internet Options > Content > Clear SSL State` ?

Comment: That made no difference. I am confident that the SSL Certificate is SOMEWHERE else on the server, either a site that I don't see, or in Exchange System Manager itself. If I browse to OWA with SSL, it works fine, so I know the certificate is installed correctly.

Comment: I'd check this article: [Assign Services to a Certificate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351257)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this also sounds like this could be a problem with working in Exchange Cached mode.

Perhaps you can try to switch it of in your account settings and restart Outlook. If it works again you can turn cached mode back on. Good luck